# sublime text next_result open blank file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a customized build system in sublime text 3. However the output has mixed "(filename:line number)" of my source code and the library source code. When I use next_result/prev_result to navigate the errors, it will open a blank tab for the library source code because the path is not right. It is annoying to close these blank tab every time. Can I configure sublime not to open a blank file tab when it cannot find the source file? Thanks.